# UITapGestureRecognizer not working after the size of a UIScrollView containing a UIImageView is changed

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView with a perfectly working attached UITapGestureRecognizer. That's not where the problem is, but I'm adding the code snippet which adds the gesture to give more context:

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(
                            target: self,
                            action: Selector("didTapImageView:")
                           )
imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

This is the issue: the ImageView is inside a ScrollView that is resized depending on the device. The resize also works as expected, but when it happens, the UIImageView does not recognize the tap gesture anymore. Everything gets perfectly displayed, but tapping on the image does not trigger the didTapImageView method. Only if the scroll view is rezised.

The resizing of the UIScrollView happens inside a `imagePickerController(picker, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo)` delegate method. Here it is:

```
let currentViewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height
if currentViewHeight < heightLimit {
    let frameRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: currentViewHeight + offset)
    let frameSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.frame.size.width, height: currentViewHeight + offset)
    scrollView.frame = frameRect
    scrollView.contentSize = frameSize
}
```

How can I prevent the gesture recognizer from getting cancelled?